# CXF InstrumentationManagerImpl bean with more than 1 CXF app in the container

Tags: java, spring, cxf, jmx

I'm having a problem when trying to deploy 2 or more CXF apps in the same container. The problem is with org.apache.cxf.management.jmx.InstrumentationManagerImpl ... in that more than 1 deployment produces;

`Jan 18, 2011 2:05:10 PM ...InstrumentationManagerImpl init
SEVERE: START_CONNECTOR_FAILURE_MSG`

The bean configuration looks like this:

**App One**

```
<bean id="OneInstrumentationManager" class="org.apache.cxf.management.jmx.InstrumentationManagerImpl">
    <property name="bus" ref="cxf" />
    <property name="enabled" value="true" />
    <property name="usePlatformMBeanServer" value="true" />
    <property name="persistentBusId" value="One" />
</bean>
```

**App Two**

```
<bean id="TwoInstrumentationManager" class="org.apache.cxf.management.jmx.InstrumentationManagerImpl">
    <property name="bus" ref="cxf" />
    <property name="enabled" value="true" />
    <property name="usePlatformMBeanServer" value="true" />
    <property name="persistentBusId" value="Two" />
</bean>
```

Comment: Please use the code formatter correctly, you're not making people want to read this.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I did to get 2 [actually 3] to work in the same container... **nothing more nothing less**;

```
<bean id="MyCxfExampleInstrumentationManager" class="org.apache.cxf.management.jmx.InstrumentationManagerImpl">
    <property name="bus" ref="cxf" />
    <property name="enabled" value="true" />
    <property name="usePlatformMBeanServer" value="true" />
    <property name="createMBServerConnectorFactory" value="false" />
</bean>

<bean id="MyCxfExampleCounterRepository" class="org.apache.cxf.management.counters.CounterRepository">
    <property name="bus" ref="cxf" />
</bean>
```

Comment: I think you'll find setting "persistentBusId" is your problem.

Answer (score 1):

We faced the same JMX ObjectName collision problem with CXF and EhCache.

The solution we found is to append the context-path of the web app to each ObjectName registered in the MBeanServer. This is directly inspired by the federated MBeansServers of big clusterisable JavaEE server (Websphere, etc).

Thanks to this, the cxf bus ObjectName is :

```
"org.apache.cxf:type=Bus,host=localhost,path=/my-application,bus.id=my-application-cxf-bus"
```

We packaged this "[servlet context aware mbean server](http://code.google.com/p/xebia-france/wiki/ServletContextAwareMbeanServer)" in a library with a spring namespace to ease configuration:

```
<beans 
   xmlns:management="http://www.xebia.fr/schema/xebia-management-extras"
   ... >

   <management:servlet-context-aware-mbean-server id="mbeanServer" />

   <bean id="cxf" class="org.apache.cxf.bus.CXFBusImpl">
      <property name="id" value="production-ready-application-cxf-bus" />
   </bean>
   <bean id="org.apache.cxf.management.InstrumentationManager" class="org.apache.cxf.management.jmx.InstrumentationManagerImpl">
      <property name="server" ref="mbeanServer" />
      <property name="enabled" value="true" />
      <property name="createMBServerConnectorFactory" value="false" />
   </bean>
   ...
<beans>
```

This **<servlet-context-aware-mbean-server />** is packaged with many other JMX extras to ease monitoring of common components (dbcp, util.concurrent, cxf, jms, etc) and proposed under a business friendly Apache Software License at http://code.google.com/p/xebia-france/wiki/XebiaManagementExtras .

Hope this helps,

Cyrille (Xebia)